# Excel UDF - Gives #Value error when referencing another workbook sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new here. Pardon me if I make mistakes and would appreciate if someone gave me pointers if I did something wrong.

My problem is related to creating a UDF which would give out a proposal no from another workbook sheet by matching the YEAR & NAME from the current workbook. The current code gives a #VALUE error.

```
Function ProposalNo(BorrowerName As String, Year As String) As String
Dim PropNo As String
Dim BorrowerName As String
Dim Year As String
Dim CMISPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Match As Double

CMISPath = "C:\Users\15169\Desktop\Data Dump\CMIS\SME- CMIS.xlsb"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CMISPath)
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If (JW(Trim(UCase(CStr(BorrowerName))), Trim(UCase(sht.Cells(i, 11).Value))) >= 0.85 And CStr(Year) = CStr(sht.Cells(i, 10).Value)) Then
                PropNo = sht.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    ProposalNo = PropNo
End Function
```

JW is another function which basically tries to match the Borrower Name using a percentage match function. The #Value error occurs due to `Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. I tried creating another function to assign the sheet details but that didn't work. I would be grateful if someone could give me some pointers.

Comment: see my answer below, let me know if it helped you

Comment: Add the line: MsgBox wb.Name below the line where you Set wb and before you set ws. If that gives you anything other than "SME- CMIS", you know it is in the setting of the workbook. For troubleshooting, you can also try changing the function into a sub and seeing if that makes your trouble line successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a User Defined Function (UDF) ["must not modify the contents or formatting of any cell and must not modify the operating environment of Excel"](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx).

So the needed workbook must be already open at the time you want to use the function and have it only set it to given (or passed) workbook name

here is the corresponding refactoring of your UDF:

```
Function ProposalNo(BorrowerName As String, Year As String) As String
    Dim PropNo As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Const WBNAME As String = "SME- CMIS.xlsb"
    Const SHEETNAME As String = "Sheet1"

    Set sht = GetSheet(WBNAME, SHEETNAME)
    If sht Is Nothing Then
        ProposalNo = "couldn't fine sheet '" & SHEETNAME & "' in workbook '" & WBNAME & "'"
    Else
        With sht
            For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If (JW(Trim(UCase(CStr(BorrowerName))), Trim(UCase(sht.Cells(i, 11).value))) >= 0.85 And CStr(Year) = CStr(sht.Cells(i, 10).value)) Then
                    ProposalNo = sht.Cells(i, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Function

Function GetSheet(WBNAME As String, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Workbooks(WBNAME).Worksheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just as I wanted it to. I have a question though. My code refused to work simply because of the way I referenced the CMIS sheet. Is the way I referenced an external workbook wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the full answer (as i don't know what **Function *JW*** does).
A few corrections for your code:

1.Remove the following 2 variables declarations (as they are passed through when calling this function):

```
 Dim BorrowerName As String
 Dim Year As String
```

The following line :

`Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`  - works for me, are you sure you have a sheet called "**Sheet1**" in your `wb` called "**SME- CMIS.xlsb**"

3.Once you were able to set Sheet variable `sht` correctly, then in the following line you can use:

```
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

**General message** : use `Option Explicit` in the begining, it would have resolved half of these errors.

(don't forget to define `Dim i As Long` , before running your `For` loop).

4.**And last**, you defined this function to receive `BorrowerName As String, Year As String`, therefore, in the following line you don't need to use the `Cstr` :

```
If (JW(Trim(UCase(CStr(BorrowerName))), Trim(UCase(sht.Cells(i, 11).Value))) >= 0.85 And CStr(Year) = CStr(sht.Cells(i, 10).Value)) Then
```

Just use:

```
If (JW(Trim(UCase(BorrowerName)), Trim(UCase(sht.Cells(i, 11).Value))) >= 0.85 And Year = CStr(sht.Cells(i, 10).Value)) Then
```

The whole code (without being able to test ***JW* function**):

```
Option Explicit

Function ProposalNo(BorrowerName As String, Year As String) As String

Dim PropNo As String
Dim CMISPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Match As Double
Dim i As Long

CMISPath = "C:\Users\15169\Desktop\Data Dump\CMIS\SME- CMIS.xlsb"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CMISPath)
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ((JW(Trim(UCase(BorrowerName)), Trim(UCase(sht.Cells(i, 11).Value))) >= 0.85) And (Year = CStr(sht.Cells(i, 10).Value))) Then
        PropNo = sht.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next

ProposalNo = PropNo

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I apologize for replying late. I tried your code. Somehow whenever I use the UDF it returns #VALUE!, the same one I faced. In my code, the error was solved if I included the sheet in my workbook and modified the code but it won't always be an option for me. I can't seem to wrap my head around the fact that the issue is somehow related to how I am referencing the CMIS sheet.